# RunProcessAsUser causing problems

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-server-2008-r2, impersonation

I have an application that is being started by a Service automatically when the user logs on to his account. The application in question is a Winforms application and the problem is that sometimes when the application is started from the service it inexplicably hangs. Killing it and running it once more without a service works fine.

I am not sure why this is happening and why it only happens occasionally (not all the time). I always check the new process information and it is always running under the correct session of the logged in user.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong when impersonating the user but in any case I am listing the code just so that maybe someone can find a flaw in it:

```
public int RunWithTokenInSession(IntPtr token, int nSessionID)
{

    IntPtr primaryToken = GetUserTokenOfSessoin((uint)nSessionID);
    if (primaryToken == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
       return -1;
    }

    STARTUPINFO StartupInfo = new STARTUPINFO();
    processInfo_ = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
    StartupInfo.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(StartupInfo);
    //StartupInfo.wShowWindow = (short)ShowCommands.SW_HIDE;
    StartupInfo.lpDesktop = "Winsta0\\Default";

    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Security1 = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES Security2 = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();

    string command = "\"" + processPath_ + "\"";
    if ((arguments_ != null) && (arguments_.Length != 0))
    {
        command += " " + arguments_;
    }

    IntPtr lpEnvironment = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool resultEnv = CreateEnvironmentBlock(out lpEnvironment, primaryToken, false);
    if (resultEnv != true)
    {
        int nError = GetLastError();
    }

    bool b = CreateProcessAsUser(primaryToken, null, command, ref Security1, ref Security2, false, /*CREATE_NO_WINDOW | NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS |*/ CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT | DETACHED_PROCESS, lpEnvironment, null, ref StartupInfo, out processInfo_);
    int error = 0;
    if (!b)
    {
        error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        string message = String.Format("CreateProcessAsUser Error: {0}", error);
        Debug.WriteLine(message);
    }
    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment);
    CloseHandle(primaryToken);

    return error;
}
```

And this is the code for `GetUserTokenOfSessoin`:

```
public static IntPtr GetUserTokenOfSessoin(uint dwSessionId)
{
    IntPtr currentToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;

    IntPtr hUserToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr hTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero;


    bool bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(dwSessionId, out currentToken);
    if (bRet == false)
    {
        int n = GetLastError();
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }


    bool fInAdminGroup = false;
    //IntPtr hToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr hTokenToCheck = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr pElevationType = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr pLinkedToken = IntPtr.Zero;
    int cbSize = 0;


    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
    {
        // Running Windows Vista or later (major version >= 6).
        // Determine token type: limited, elevated, or default.

        // Allocate a buffer for the elevation type information.
        cbSize = sizeof(TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE);
        pElevationType = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cbSize);
        if (pElevationType == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        // Retrieve token elevation type information.
        if (!GetTokenInformation(currentToken,
            TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenElevationType, pElevationType, cbSize, out cbSize))
        {
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        }

        // Marshal the TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE enum from native to .NET.
        TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE elevType = (TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE)Marshal.ReadInt32(pElevationType);

        // If limited, get the linked elevated token for further check.
        if (elevType == TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE.TokenElevationTypeLimited)
        {
            // Allocate a buffer for the linked token.
            cbSize = IntPtr.Size;
            pLinkedToken = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cbSize);
            if (pLinkedToken == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            // Get the linked token.
            if (!GetTokenInformation(currentToken, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenLinkedToken, pLinkedToken, cbSize, out cbSize))
            {
                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            // Marshal the linked token value from native to .NET.
            hTokenToCheck = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pLinkedToken);
            bRet = DuplicateTokenEx(hTokenToCheck, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out primaryToken);


        }
        else
        {
            bRet = DuplicateTokenEx(currentToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out primaryToken);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // XP
        bRet = DuplicateTokenEx(currentToken, TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, IntPtr.Zero, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out primaryToken);
    }

    if (bRet == false)
    {
        int lastError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    return primaryToken;
}
```

Now the issue seems to exclusively happen on Windows Server 2008 R2 as I haven't been able to reproduce it on any other version of Windows so I was wondering if there is anything special about Server 2008 and do I need to take extra security measures or obtain an extra privilege to run the process as the user.

Comment: Out of the hand I'd guess it's a timing issue in the application that gets started (Kind of: Start and then wait for some task to finish, but the task happens to be finished already.). Principally, if it's not the service that hangs, I'd rather search in the client application... (still means that the service can be responsible due to incorrect initialization. But it's difficult to say what the "correct" initialization must be without looking at the client)

Comment: Attach the debugger with Tools + Attach to Process, enable both managed and unmanaged debugging, look at the stack trace to see where it hangs.  Update your question with the stack trace if you need more help.

Comment: @HansPassant the problem is that all threads of the application seems to run normally it is as if the client application UI is the only thing that is frozen. And no matter how I tried to force refreshing it, it is just stuck.